# How to write the actual text value &quot; or &amp; in HTML Code

Tags: html

I have a peculiar situation where I have written VBA code that performs a few find/replace actions on HTML special character codes.

I am trying to publish this code to my website in HTML format, but the part where my code references codes like `&quot;` or `&amp;` are turning into the actual HTML characters (eg `&`).

Is there an HTML trick to prevent this from happening, so I can literally display the text `&quot;` or `&amp;` in my HTML code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may escape it by using a mixture of XML Escaped code and plain text in HTML.

```html
<body>
<ul>
<li>&amp; = &amp;amp;</li>
<li>&apos; = &amp;apos;</li>
<li>&quot; = &amp;quot;</li>
<li>&lt; = &amp;lt;</li>
<li>&gt; = &amp;gt;</li>
</ul>
</body>
```